# Can a package be shared between projects?

Tags: ssis

Is there any way to share a SSIS package (2012) between projects? I'm wanting to have a single place to edit the shared package, but then have it compiled into different SSIS projects, and have available for use with the execute package task (as a project reference).

Comment: I cam't comment for 2012 but in prior versions a package is just a file which could in theory be added to any number of projects. Do you have an 'add existing' option in SSIS 2012?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
It is possible from SQL server 2012 onwards.

If you have packages distributed in more than 1 projects, deploy them in an 'Integration services catalog'. There are built in SSIS stored procedures which gives the developer full control over the deployed packages.

```
Eg: 
catalog.set_execution_parameter_value is used to pass parameter values.
catalog.create_execution is used to initiate the package execution
```

See the complete list here.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878034%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm talking about, or it's not obvious how it applies. I want to have a package that can truncate data from any set of tables, disable any set of foreign keys (I have these packages now) that I can call from different projects. Like a library package. The package has parameters to passing list of tables or FKs, so it really isn't project specific. I'd be totally fine (even prefer) if this happened on the development side, so I just need to deploy the project and the common package is included in it.